# Adding two separate {content} areas in Weebly HTML editor

Tags: html, editor, sections, weebly

I am attempting to add two {content} areas on my Weebly website that are separated by custom code in the HTML/CSS editor. I am not understanding the basic fundamentals to how {content} sections work in Weebly.

I initially copied and pasted:

```
<section id="wb_sections">
    {{#sections}}
    <div class="row">
      {content}
    </div>
    {{/sections}}
  </section>
```

But it simply duplicated the content on the page.

I am hitting a dead end in most of my searching. Please see the code below. I am trying to add a second editable (drag and drop) {content} section area between the "Portfolio" section and "footer" section. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
<body id="top" class="homepage-sections home-custom-header wsite-theme-light">
<!-- Pre Loader -->
<div id="loading" class="loading"></div>
<div class="wft-layout">
  <!-- Main Wrapper -->
  <div id="home" class="top">
    <!-- Info Bar - Text, Social -->
    <div class="info-bar">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <div class="info-left">
            <ul class="info-links clearfix">
              <li><i class="typcn typcn-time"></i>{info:text}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="info-right">
            <ul class="info-links clearfix">
              <li class="info-social">{social}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Top Bar & Menu -->
    <div class="top-bar">
      <!-- Logo, Menu, Cart-->
      <div class="header-bar ib-large">
        <div class="row d-table">
          <div class="eq-col-left pad-0">
            {logo}
          </div>
          <div class="eq-col-right pad-0">
            <div class="details-bar">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="clearfix">
                  <div class="details-right">
                    <ul class="details-links clearfix">
                      <li class="t-address"><i class="typcn typcn-location-outline"></i>{details-address:text}<br>
                        <span>{detail-address:text}</span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="t-phone"><i class="typcn typcn-phone-outline"></i>{details-phone:text}<br>
                        <span>{detail-phone:text}</span>
                      </li>
                      <li class="t-email"><i class="typcn typcn-mail"></i>{details-email:text}<br>
                        <span>{detail-email:text}</span>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-container" class="menu-container">
      <div class="row">
        <span id="cart">{minicart}</span>                       
        <!-- Menu Toggle -->
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle"></label>
        <!-- Menu -->
        <div class="menu relative">
          <div class="nm-inner">
            <!-- Scroller Menu Items -->
            <div id="scroller-nav">
              <ul id="nav">
                <li class="home-nav"><a href="#home" class="home-nav current">{menu1:text}</a></li>
                <li class="sec1-nav"><a href="#section-one" class="sec1-nav">{menu2:text}</a></li>
                <li class="sec2-nav"><a href="#section-two" class="sec2-nav">{menu3:text}</a></li>
                <li class="sec3-nav"><a href="#section-three" class="sec3-nav">{menu4:text}</a></li>
                <li class="sec4-nav"><a href="#section-four" class="sec4-nav">{menu5:text}</a></li>
                <li class="sec5-nav"><a href="#section-five" class="sec5-nav">{menu6:text}</a></li>
                <li class="blog-nav"><a href="/blog.html" class="blog-nav">{menu7:text}</a></li>
                <li class="features-nav"><a href="/features.html" class="features-nav">{menu8:text}</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Multi Page Menu -->
            <div id="multi-nav">{menu}</div>
            <!-- Mobile Menu -->
            <div id="navmobile">
              <div class="mb-inner">{menu}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Custom Header -->
  <section id="home" class="home">
    <div class="wft-banner-wrap">
      {{#header}}
      <div class="container">
        <div class="wft-banner">{content}</div>
      </div>
      {{/header}}
    </div>
  </section>
   <!-- Sections -->
  <section id="wb_sections">
    {{#sections}}
    <div class="row">
      {content}
    </div>
    {{/sections}}
  </section>
  <!-- Portfolio Section 3 -->
  <section id="section-three" class="portfolio pad-t100 relative wft-content-wrap" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <div class="row wft-ph ph-standard-3">
      {portfolio:content global="false"}
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-img-row row wft-ph ph-standard-3">
      <!-- portfolio starts here -->
      <!-- Portfolio Filter -->
      <!-- to add more title tabs, just add more <li> lines and give it a new class and {porttitle?:text} 
      <ul class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
        <li><a class="selected" href="#filter" data-option-value="*"><span></span>All</a></li>
        <li id="filter1"><a href="#filter"><span></span>{porttitle1:text}</a></li>
        <li id="filter2"><a href="#filter"><span></span>{porttitle2:text}</a></li>
        <li id="filter3"><a href="#filter"><span></span>{porttitle3:text}</a></li>
        <li id="filter4"><a href="#filter"><span></span>{porttitle4:text}</a></li>
        <li id="filter5"><a href="#filter"><span></span>{porttitle5:text}</a></li>
      </ul> -->
      <!-- End Filters -->
      <!-- Portfolio Items -->
      <div id="posts" class="row isotope ph-portfolio">
        <!-- Start Project -->
        <div id="folio1" class="post item spani4 isotope-item">
          <div class="profile-photo wft-phi">{folio1:content global="false"}</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Project -->
        <!-- Start Project -->
        <div id="folio2" class="post item spani4 isotope-item">
          <div class="profile-photo wft-phi">{folio2:content global="false"}</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Project -->
        <!-- Start Project -->
        <div id="folio3" class="post item spani4 isotope-item">
          <div class="profile-photo wft-phi">{folio3:content global="false"}</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Project -->
        <!-- Start Project -->
        <div id="folio4" class="post item spani4 isotope-item">
          <div class="profile-photo wft-phi">{folio4:content global="false"}</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Project -->
        <!-- Start Project -->
        <div id="folio5" class="post item spani4 isotope-item">
          <div class="profile-photo wft-phi">{folio5:content global="false"}</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Project -->
        <!-- Start Project -->
        <div id="folio6" class="post item spani4 isotope-item">
          <div class="profile-photo wft-phi">{folio6:content global="false"}</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Project -->
        <!-- Start Project -->
        <div id="folio7" class="post item spani4 isotope-item">
          <div class="profile-photo wft-phi">{folio7:content global="false"}</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Project -->
        <!-- Start Project -->
        <div id="folio8" class="post item spani4 isotope-item">
          <div class="profile-photo wft-phi">{folio8:content global="false"}</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Project -->
        <!-- Start Project -->
        <div id="folio9" class="post item spani4 isotope-item">
          <div class="profile-photo wft-phi">{folio9:content global="false"}</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Project -->
      </div>
      <!-- portfolio end -->
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Contact Footer -->
  <footer id="section-five" class="contact relative clearfix">
    <div class="row pad-b100 relative wft-ph ph-standard-5">
      {contact-one:content}
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
      <div class="row pad-tb25">
        <div class="twelve text-center">
          &copy; {copyright:text}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- Back to top -->
  <div class="back-top-wrap text-center">
    <a href="#top" class="scrollto"><i class="back-top relative text-center typcn typcn-arrow-up-outline"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Layout --->
<div style='display:none'>{{footer}}</div>
<!-- Javascript -->
<script>
  var para_one = jQuery('#wft-para-img1').find('img').attr('src');
  jQuery("#parallax1").css('background-image', 'url("' + para_one + '")');
  var para_two = jQuery('#wft-para-img2').find('img').attr('src');
  jQuery("#parallax2").css('background-image', 'url("' + para_two + '")');
</script>
<script src="/files/theme/jquery.home-custom.js"></script>
<script src="/files/theme/jquery.owl.js"></script>
<script src="/files/theme/jquery.home-main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is a Duplicate Question [Answered Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565834/how-to-add-a-new-section-in-weebly-template/44580946#44580946)

But, since it wasn't explained in the original, let me just point out the issue you are having. `{content}` can only be used once. For other content areas, you need a custom tag, like `{content2:content global="false"}` **Notice the custom name**  before the `:`

So, in other words, each custom content area must have a it's own custom name. Then, global="false" means it will not be duplicated on other pages. See the: [Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565834/how-to-add-a-new-section-in-weebly-template/44580946#44580946)

Comment: I read that question initially. Attempted it but kept getting a section_prefix text on my page. Thoughts as to why that might be happening?

Comment: Here is the code I am using

<section id="wb_sections">
        {{#sections}}
        <div class="row">
          {section2:content global="false"}
        </div>
        {{/sections}}
      </section>

Comment: You would have to contact Weebly about the section_prefix issue. That appears to be a Weebly Development issue.. that they may already be aware of. It's possible they do not allow multiple {{#sections}} tags, so that will not work, and you can only add custom content areas.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, Jeffrey!